# Rails: Allow only specific symbols and letters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby

Trying to write correct validation.

I have symbols/letters which can be only used:

```
ALLOWED_SYMBOLS = %w(/ @ _ + - ( ) . , : ? ' & ; " 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A a Ā ā Ą ą Ä ä B b C c Č č D d E e Ē ē Ę ę Ė ė F f G g Ģ ģ H h I i Ī ī Į į Y y J j K k Ķ ķ L l Ļ ļ M m N n Ņ ņ O o Õ õ Ö ö P p Q q R r S s Š š T t U u Ū ū Ü ü V v W w Z z Ž ž X x)
```

Afterwards i'm trying to validate it

```
validates :reference inclusion: { in: ALLOWED_SYMBOLS, allow_blank: true }
```

But it's not working properly as if i'm writing 2 or more allowed symbols i get an error, it does not happen when i type only 1 allowed one.

Looking forward for your help. The idea is to only allow mentioned symbols(they can be duplicated and such)

Rails 5.2

Comment: I would solve this with a regex match. However, one question: Is there a better way to define the list of "allowed symbols"? What does that list actually represent? Why  is `ö` and `õ` allowed, but `ó` and `ò` aren't? My linguistic knowledge isn't good enough to immediately know what language/character set you're trying to represent, but perhaps at a bare minimum you could use a more descriptive variable name than `ALLOWED_SYMBOLS`?

Comment: Hey @TomLord. Well, this was the request. variable name is just for a preview here ;)

Comment: Part of the job of a developer should be to understand the request of a client; converting confusing requests into code (even the order of letters in this alphabet is wrong??!!) is asking for trouble, because there's a high chance you're not actually solving the problem they needed.

Comment: In the interest of making progress on a solution I'd give an answer below. However, for example, if this is supposed to be "Slovakian letters" then there may be a more comprehensive/concise way of solving it, e.g. using well-defined, built-in character sets or unicode ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that validating `inclusion: {in: ...}` is saying "the value must be **one of the items in the list**" -- which is not what you want at all.

Instead, what you're trying to check is "does `reference` only contain characters from this list?".

I would solve that with a regex. Suppose, for example, you wanted a string to only contain the characters `a, b, c, d, ..., z`. Then you could check the format with:

```rb
/\A[a-z]*\z/
```

Where `\A` means "start of string", `\z` means "end of string" and `[a-z]*` means "zero or more letters from the collection: `a, b, c, ...., z`".

However, your scenario is a *little* more awkward because you don't have a nice character set/range like `[a-z]`. You *could* write that very verbosely (but it's difficult to read/reuse the code):

```rb
/\A[\/@_+\-().,:?'&;"0123456789ĀāĄąÄäBb....]*\z/
```

Or, better, you could get a little fancy and convert the constant into a suitable regex:

```rb
/\A#{Regexp.union(*ALLOWED_SYMBOLS)}*\z/
```

---

And therefore your final answer is to replace this:

```rb
validates :reference inclusion: { in: ALLOWED_SYMBOLS, allow_blank: true }
```

With this:

```rb
validates :reference, format: { with: /\A#{Regexp.union(*ALLOWED_SYMBOLS)}*\z/ }
```

See also: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html